# SQL executeBatch slow processing

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Basically i have to read a csv file and perform some validation. 
If duplicate record is found i've to delete the previous record and insert the latest 1.
The file contains about 100k records. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrongly but it's taking way too long to load the data.

```
  public static ArrayList<BootstrapMessage> loadLocation(File file) {
    ArrayList<BootstrapMessage> errors = new ArrayList<BootstrapMessage>();
    CSVReader reader = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    Connection conn2 = null;

    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {
        conn = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
        conn2 = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(INSERT_LOCATION);
        ps = conn2.prepareStatement("delete from location where `timestamp` = ? AND mac_address = ?");
        reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"));
        reader.readNext();//header
        String[] record = reader.readNext();
        int counter = 2;//starting from line 2. Line 1 is header
        int validRecords = 0;
        while (record != null) {
            ArrayList<String> message = null;
            //try {
            message = ValidatorUtil.validateLocation(record, file.getName(), counter);

            if (message != null) {//contains error
                errors.add(new BootstrapMessage(file.getName(), counter, message));
            } else {//valid record
                String key = record[0] + record[1];
                if (locations.containsKey(key)) {//duplicate found.
                    pstmt.executeBatch();
                    message = new ArrayList<String>();
                    message.add("duplicate row");
                    errors.add(new BootstrapMessage(file.getName(), locations.get(key), message));
                    //delete record from database 
                    ps.setTimestamp(1, Timestamp.valueOf(record[0]));
                    ps.setString(2, record[1]);
                    ps.executeUpdate();
                    //inserting the latest record
                    pstmt.setTimestamp(1, Timestamp.valueOf(record[0]));
                    pstmt.setString(2, record[1]);
                    pstmt.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(record[2]));
                    pstmt.addBatch();
                    if (validRecords % 2000 == 0) {
                        pstmt.executeBatch();
                    }
                } else {
                    pstmt.setTimestamp(1, Timestamp.valueOf(record[0]));
                    pstmt.setString(2, record[1]);
                    pstmt.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(record[2]));
                    pstmt.addBatch();
                    validRecords++;
                    if (validRecords % 2000 == 0) {
                        pstmt.executeBatch();
                    }
                }

            }

            if (validRecords > 0) {
                pstmt.executeBatch();
                conn.commit();
            }
            record = reader.readNext();
            counter++;
        }

        System.out.println("valid location records = " + validRecords);
        //numOfValidRecords.put(fileName, validRecords);
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            return errors;
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LocationDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LocationDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LocationDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(LocationDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        ConnectionManager.close(conn2, ps);
        ConnectionManager.close(conn, pstmt);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use native database loaders to do the job?
Or I would first insert all the records into staging and then do the duplicate  removals by using the database tools, either SQL or some database procedure. This way it has to be faster.

Comment: I need to capture the duplicate record and report which line is it conflicting with. I've tried using INFILE, but i couldn't capture the duplicate that way.

Comment: I understood, but still I would suggest loading into the staging table and then do the data manipulation.